# Can I use factors from Factor analyses (EFA) in random forest or SVM models?

Tags: svm, random-forest, factor-analysis

I want to use factors which I get from Factor analysis in random forest model.
Is it possible?
I am trying to do it, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me ?

I describe factors like this:

```
f1 <-Numeric_data [ , c("Age" , "Fault" , "Income")]
f2 <-Numeric_data [ , c("Term." , "DSTI" , "Income")]
f3 <-Numeric_data [ , c("Fault" , "Court" , "Faust_days")]
```

Model which I tried:

```
model_P2P <-randomForest(Fraud ~ f1 +f2 +f3 , data = train, ntree=7, proximity=TRUE, mtry = 7)
```

What I get:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Sukciavimas ~ f1 + f2 + f3, data = train,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'f1')